# What's the geometric interpretation of a semidenifite matrix smaller than identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

What's the geometric interpretation of a semidenifite matrix in terms of eigenvalues/eigenvectors with the condition:
$$
0 \preceq W \preceq I
$$

Comment: Can you specify what $\preceq$ means? Also do you mean to say $\text{... interpretation of a semidefinite matrix }W\text{ in terms ...}$?

Comment: it means "positive semidefinite(psd)".

Comment: It means the partial ordering under the semidefinite cone. That is, $A\preceq B$ iff $B-A$ is PSD.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant Thanks.

Comment: that means matrix $W-I$ should be psd which $I$ is an diagonal matrix.

Comment: @SaberMüler, may we assume $W$ is symmetric or Hermitian? Generally in this context we do.

Comment: @Michael C. Grant, actually $W$ is symmetric Laplacian matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $W$ is positive semidefinite, so it can be diagonalised and has non-negative eigenvalues. Hence, it has some directions which is "stretches" or "shrinks" by some (positive) factor, and it also may collapse some of these direction if eigenvalues are $0$. The "shrinking" happens for eigenvalues less than $1$, and "stretching" --- more than $1$. The condition $W \preceq I$ says that the eigenvalues are all at most $1$ --- hence, $W$ just "shrinks" the space.

Answer (score 1):

If we may assume that $W$ is symmetric or Hermitian, which is nearly always the case when talking about semidefinite matrices, then this expression simply states that the eigenvalues of $W$ are all between 0 and 1, inclusive. No conditions are imposed on the eigenvectors.